# File Operation Plugin for Jenkins - overwriting files

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I can't find any information on whether [File Operation commands](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/) such as fileCopyOperations, overwrite the files in the destination directory. The Jenkins documentation is very sparse on this. Does anyone have information about that?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?